# How to safely reload server side javascript functions on the fly?

Tags: java, nashorn

I am experimenting with Nashorn and calling js functions from Java code.  I have a WatchService that reloads changed files and reevaluates the ScriptEngine

```
engine.eval(Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(scriptFile), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

It seems to work fairly well, however, there have been a couple times where I saved the javascript file with unsuspecting typos inside and the subsequent attempt to invoke function

```
invoker.invokeFunction("printServiceReport", tesla);
```

causes a javax.script.ScriptException to be thrown thereby killing my running code.  Looking for a workable solution to reload logic in real-time without negatively disrupting my application.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your eval of each code file in a try catch as well as your invokes.

If you need to, you can run through all your functions on reload to see if errors occur - and then use the old version instead if errors are found (if detecting errors at runtime is unacceptable).

We do something similar to that when we reload our serverside scripts.